# Jbutton shows up in front of jpanel on jlayeredpane when moving mouse over it

Tags: java, swing

I have a JLayeredPane, with a JButton and JPanel. Both are the same size and at the same location. The JPanel is transparent with a LineBorder and the button also, so that there is another border in front of the Jbutton, but when I move the mouse over the panel the Button appears in front of it. I want the button to move and JPanel to stay put, but why does the JButton move in front of the JPanel when moving mouse over it?

Comment: If camickr's answer does not solve your problem then: 1) add more detail to your question, and pertinent code, preferably an [mcve] -- please check out the link, and 2) leave a comment to his answer explaining your problem and your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> , but why does the JButton move in front of the JPanel when moving mouse over it?

Mouse events are generated as you move your mouse around the frame.

In this case a "mouse entered" event is being generated as the mouse moves over the button. By default a button has a rollover effect and the button needs to be painted, so it is painted on top of the panel.

Not sure, buy you might be able to turn off this effect by using:

```
button.setRolloverEnabled( false );
```

However, when you click the button you will have the same problem.